# int cannot be converted to int []

Tags: java, arrays, bluej

new to programming here and i keep getting the error message, `incompatible types, int cannot be converted to int []`, the question is to add `R1` & `R2` together if they are of equal lengths and if not, print a message that says **'the arrays must be same length'**, if that matters, not sure where im going wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated

```java
public int[] arrayAdd(int[] R1, int[] R2)
    {
        int[] sumArray= new int[R1.length];
       
        if( R1.length!= R2.length)
        {
            System.out.println("The arrays must be same length");
    }
    else
    {
       for(int i=0; i< R1.length; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<R2.length; j++)
       
        {
          
            sumArray= R1[i]+ R2[j]; // Error
        }
    }
        return sumArray;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to assign an int to `sumArray`?

Comment: `sumArray[i] = R1[i]+ R2[j];`.

Comment: your code doesn't have matching braces and won't compile. And why do you allocate a new array before checking if 2 lengths are equal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
           sumArray[i]= R1[i]+ R2[j]; // updated line
```

you need to assign to an array element, but you were doing it wrong.

Comment: This is not the way arrays should be dynamically allocated.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès
If you see the code above, I just edited one line from OP's code. So, it wasnt my concern whether OP uses ArrayList, Array or how he handle resources. I was just correcting one step where he was doing wrong.

Comment: Giving an answer which is itself bad code, isn't an answer. So give the correct line but don't post wrong code!

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès
I just edited my answer to avoid any **misinterpretations**. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

> not sure where im going wrong

You are attempting to assign an `int` to a variable whose type is `int[]`.

That is not legal ... and it doesn't make sense.

This:

```
   sumArray= R1[i]+ R2[j];
```

should be this

```
   sumArray[something_or_other] = R1[i] + R2[j];
```

... except that you have a bunch of other errors which mean that a simple "point fix" won't be correct.

Hint: you do not need nested loops to add the elements of two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is broken in many several ways, at least:

1. You declared returning an array but what is the value of it when inputs are of the wrong size? Manage such errors in better ways (stop, throw exception, return error code, etc). At least never display something at this place, this is not the place were you have to tackle the error, this is the place here you detect it, just report it to caller(s).
2. You (tried to) created space for the returned value but how could this be if conditions for having a return value is not met?
3. You used Java syntax to declare an array, `int []sumArray` should be `int sumArray[0].
4. You can't dynamically allocate an array like this, to capture a dynamic allocation you must use a pointer, an array is not a pointer. But a pointer can be set to the memory address of an allocated array, like `int *sumArray = new int[10]`
5. `sumArray` is an array so to set an element of it use `sumArray[index] = ...`

So this may be better:

```
public int *arrayAdd(int[] R1, int[] R2) {
    if( R1.length!= R2.length) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    int *sumArray= new int[R1.length];
    for(int i=0; i< R1.length; i++) {    
        sumArray[i] = R1[i]+ R2[i]; 
    }
    return sumArray;
}
```

---

After question editing

If you want to sum two arrays, element by element, then a single loop is sufficient...

Answer (score -1):

Actually in that line sumArray is an integer array and you are assigning it as integer only and also you haven't declared variable j.
Try this-

```
public int[] arrayAdd(int[] R1, int[] R2)
{
    int[] sumArray= new int[R1.length];

    if( R1.length!= R2.length)
    {
        System.out.println("The arrays must be same length");
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=0; i< R1.length; i++)

        {

            sumArray[i]= R1[i]+ R2[i]; // Error
        }
    }
    return sumArray;
}
```